# Geometry Nodes - Vertex Group to Edge path (Curve)

Tags: geometry-nodes, edges, vertex-groups

[image]

Is there any way to get edge path (curve) from *Vertex Group* ?

[image: The desired edges]

But obviusly geometry nodes setup of mine gives me not what I want.

[image: My undesired result]

Comment: I'm really start thinking, that it is impossible, because is you press "select" button  in vgroup you will get messy result which will be produces in geomery nodes

Comment: How about using an edge group (custom Attribute) instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leander is totally right.

You cannot use vertex groups because they don't (!) select clearly an edge. Mostly they select too much, because if two vertices of one edge are selected/weighted, the edge is selected as well, but you don't want this in this case.
So what you need, is an edge attribute (selected or not).

[image]

So go to attributes, create an edge attribute float, select that attribute, go in edit mode, select your "path" in edge select mode -> mesh -> set attribute

[image]

then change your gn tree to this:

[image]

result:

[image]

note: i did not (!) use your edge selection, i created my own, so it looks different to yours.